# html pagination and 'paged media'

Tags: html, css, css-paged-media

Is there a way to create paginated content (display separated pages horizontally/vertically) using `CSS` 'paged media' features?

Comment: Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/page.html

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "paginated content" exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I'm interpreting the question correctly:

CSS paged media features are used to describe the presentation when some form of pagination has to take place (usually when a web page is being printed onto distinct sheets of paper).

They cannot be used to divide content up into sections and generate links between them.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go i was going to write the full explanation. but this tutorial has already done that for me:

http://www.cssdog.com/css_paged_media.html

check it out.

Let me know if that helped.
Thanks

**PK**