# Jquery Dynamic Book Style Pagination Based on Container Size

Tags: jquery, dynamic, pagination

If you've ever used a eReader app that's what I am trying to create. I want to load a HUGE amount of text, and then break it into pages. Those "page breaks" should occur when text starts to overflow or get cut off in any way. I've tried exploring a variety of ways to do this but I haven't had much luck.

Right now I am trying to break every single word out (awful and slow) and measure how far from the top it is, after it gets to a certain height I am trying to edit the html to close the last page and start a new one.

I want to avoid separating the content after a certain number of characters or words since that is inconsistent. The document may have HTML in it too.

To be frank, I don't even know where to start and I've been looking for some hint at how to proceed for quite a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a non-trivial task. To give you some idea of what you're up against, take a look at this: http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/2009/HPL-2009-123.pdf.

This question is similar: [html pagination and 'paged media'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849598/html-pagination-and-paged-media)

It would be nice if you could use the [W3C paged media CSS standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/page.html), as suggested there but it's [not yet well supported](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28Cascading_Style_Sheets%29#Grammar_and_rules) in any of [firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=115199), chrome or safari. Shocking but this appears to be one of the rare cases where IE is ahead of the curve.

I also strongly suspect that you should find a way to load segments of text. Loading HUGE amounts of text is going to hog up memory, slow down your page and generally muck up your user's browser.